# How to show a button after 5 seconds in android studio?

Tags: android

I have an app that shows a disclaimer at the beginning of the program. I want a button to remain invisible for 5 seconds, and then become visible. I set up a thread that sleeps for 5 seconds, and then tries to make the button visible. However, I get this error when I execute my code:

```
08-02 21:34:07.868: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1401):
```

How can I count 5 seconds, and then make the button visible?

Answer (score 3):

```
yourButton.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!getActivity().isFinishing()) { // make checks to see if activity is still available
                yourButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }, 1000 * 5);    // 5 seconds
```

Comment: please where i add my button intent  Intent i = new Intent(frst.this,scnd.class);
                        startActivity(i);
 ? + i get methode cannot resloved for getActivity and setVisibility

Answer (score 1):

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //your code
                }
            } 
        }
    }, 5000);
```